# HTML5 offline webapp communication with Modbus TCP/IP

Tags: html, web-applications, modbus

Even if I think it's not possible, I would be sure by asking this to you :
Is it possible to create a webapp (offline/online) to communicate with a machine using Modbus TCP/IP without an external server ?

Here is the point :
We sell machines, which send and receive informations using Modbus TCP/IP, and we would like to create a standalone webapp using pure HTML5 offline cache manifest features that could communicate with them without passing by an external server (except for the first time launch for receiving configurations and save them to localStorage).

I don't think these could be done, but I would be very happy if I'm wrong ;-)

I discovered TooTallNate using Node.js, and I have already used phpmodbus, but these need a server between the device (smartphone or desktop browser) and the machines.

So my question is : is it possible ? And if so, which Javascript library can I use if exists, or where can I find needed informations ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with JavaScript.

Because of security, JavaScript can not access to local resources (Ports, File etc..)